# Formal power series ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is a formal power series ring over $k$, where $k$ is an algebriac closed field. $I,J$ are ideals of $A$.

If $\phi:A/I\rightarrow A/J$ is a surjection. Can we induce a $k-$algebra automorphism of $A$ by $\phi$ to make the corresponding diagram commutative?

So it’s equivalent to following questiion:

If $\psi:A\rightarrow A/I$ is a surjection(may not be canonical).

Can we induce a $k-$algebra automorphism of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I$ is contained in the square of the maximal ideal, any lift will give you an automorphism of $A$. This is also true even if $I$ contains a variable (but no longer any lift) and I will let you think about it.

Comment: Yes, when $I$ is contained in the square of the maximal ideal, the answer is very obvious. And If $I$ contains a variable. We can extend the elements of inverse image to a basis in $M/M^2$ and let the part extended correspond to the variable contained in $I$